# VBA - Remove cell that contains word from same column

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen similar posts out there but not quite the same and seem to be confused on the results I'm getting...

I essentially need to de-dupe a column on LIKE words, so it's somewhat straightforward but apparently not as easy as I thought.

*I have a dataset like soo...*

[image: I have a dataset like so...]

When I run my macro it removes rows (as I intended), but doesn't seem to remove all the rows or the wrong rows...

*It actually removes the highlighted/yellow rows*

[image: It actually removes the highlighted/yellow rows]

I was thinking it should actually remove something like the bottom rows.. where it would keep "aerospace" but remove "aerospace 2019", since the 2019 is kinda redundant and not applicable to me.

My macro is simple, but I thought it would do the trick... what am I doing wrong?

```
Sub container()

Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Long, col As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever


i = 2
    'For col = 2 To 5 'placeholder in case multiple columns are needed - remove Set col above
        For rw = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'from row 1 til last non-empty row
            v = ws.Cells(rw, 2).Value 'set range
                If Cells(i, 2).Value Like v Then 'determine if the cell contains the value of the word
                    Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete 'delete
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next rw
'Next col

End Sub
```

After Ron's post I was able to create the below, but appears I'm still stuck. I think I've just been looking at this too long.

```
Sub container()

Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long, rw As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) 'set array range

i = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For rw = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 2
        v = ws.Cells(rw, 2).Value
            If InStr(1, v, rng) > 0 Then
                    cell.EntireRow.Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: The `Like` operator doesn't work the way you think it does. Read the documentation closely.  The only reason **any** lines are getting removed is because, the way you are going through your data, your `i` and `rw` variables are occasionally the same, hence pointing to identical values for which `Like` will return `True`. Put a break at the delete row line, examine the variables at that point, and you will see what I mean.  Also, you should really be deleting from the bottom up, else your counters will get confused.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, but appears I'm still struggling... I updated the original post with the latest..

Comment: `For rw = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 2` will only look at the last row. You have to define the `Step` since the default is `Step 1`. You probably want `Step -1`. But before doing that. define, in words, exactly how you want to compare the rows in order to determine which to delete. Computers are not capable of interpreting what you want.  You need to be very specific.  Just because you think that `a` is like `b`, does not mean the computer will interpret `like` the same way.  Make sure your written description is specific; then you can try to code it.

Comment: everyone line that has "aeronautical" in it except "aeronautical" - doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: spent more time looking at this and i could have already manually gone through it.. so alas I'm going to manually go through unless someone has a bright idea all the sudden